# deep selector for changing background color

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I've been trying to change the background color of the popover body but it's not changing the color. If I remove scoped from styles then it works but when I use scoped and use deep selector, the color doesn't apply.

This is my code

```
<template>
  <div>
     <button
       :id="callToAction"
     >click me
     </button>
     <b-popover
       :target="callToAction"
       triggers="click blur"
       custom-class="my-popover-class"
       >
         <div>Edit Me</div>
      </b-popover>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
*>>>.my-popover-class {
  background: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}
*>>>.my-popover-class .popover-body {
  color: white !important;
  background: black !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with this issue because I use Bootstrap-vue for almost all of my projects.
If I have to override any of the bootstrap components, I just simply remove the scoped from style. If you need to use scoped and also want to override bootstrap components then you should select its wrapper selector and nest it.

Comment: can you show an example of how to select the wrapper selector and nest it?

Answer (score 1):

For the first selector, you shouldn't need a deep selector, as the class is added to the root element of the popover, which has the `data-v-****` attribute from the `scoped` tag.

The second one you'll need one, but you need to place it after `.my-popover-class`. That way your selector will be rendered as `.my-popover-class[data-v-****] .popover-body`, which should work.

```html
<style scoped>
.my-popover-class {
  background: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.my-popover-class >>> .popover-body {
  color: white !important;
  background: black !important;
}
</style>
```

[Example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-jang-9298g?file=/App.vue)

Comment: i did the same but didn't work for me for some reason

Comment: Try inspecting the rendered popover in the DOM in your browser and see if it has the `data-v-***` attribute like it should.